# ui-router - nested states

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

We have the following code:

**app.js**

```
.state('app.single', {
      url: "/paths/:pathId",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/path.html",
          controller: 'PathCtrl'
        }
      }
   })

.state('app.single.comments', {
      url: "/comments",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/comments.html",
          controller: 'CommentsCtrl'
        }
      }
    });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/paths');
```

**path.html:**

```
 <a class="tab-item" href="#/app/paths/{{path.pathid}}/comments">
    <i class="icon ion-chatbox"></i>
    View Comments
 </a>
```

However, when I click on view comment, it doesn't display the view that would be generated by `templates/comments.html`. It stays on the current view `/path/:pathId`

[image]

Comment: did you include the ui-view tag in your path.html?

Comment: @cbass would you mind to elaborate more? I am developing an ionic Framework application and I did not ui-view at all. I am using ion-view instead

Comment: how are you displaying your other subviews then?

Comment: in path.html : <ion-view title="Path">

Comment: Can it be possible for you to provide a plunker or jsFiddle link?

Comment: it will take a lot of time to refactor the code to make it fit in plunkr or codepen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code within app.js should have been as:

```
.state('app.single.comments', {
   url: "/comments",
   views: {
     'menuContent@app' :{
       templateUrl: "templates/comments.html",
       controller: 'CommentsCtrl'
     }
   }
 });
```